# Query Mongo using list in a file

Tags: mongodb

I need to query Mongo for a field where the value is in a list, and then print that value plus a few others. However the list is about 4000 values long, so it is in a file. How could I do that? So something like

```
db.table.find({field1:{$eq:"abc"},"field2.subvalue":{$in:list.txt}},{"_id":1,"field2.subvalue":1,"field3":1})
```

Maybe I'm just not using the correct search terms but I can't find anything where you query from values in a file when I search Google.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, you cannot search for values that are listed in a file -- you need to pull the file in and format it as valid json array

Answer (score 0):

I second Sorens answer, try loading them into simple JSON format. for example.

```
file name : testfile
f1 f2 f3 f4 f5  -- Field
v1 v2 v3 v4 v5  --- Row one
x1 x2 x3 x4 x5  --- row two
```

your collection would look like,

collection name : testCollection

```
{
f1:v2,f2:v2,f3:v3,f4:v4,f5:v5     <--- These are documents
}
{
f1:x1,f2:x2,f3:x3,f4:x4,f5:v5
}
```

And so on and then query from MongoDB / program
Please dont do this manually for 4k fields , that's a nightmare :).
Google around for some java or python code and have that do it for you.
Good luck